# MySQL View: Union Query Fails

Tags: mysql, view, union

I'm trying to create a view based on the following query, which works fine as a query:

```
SELECT x_doc_status.Status, sort_order FROM x_doc_status WHERE sort_order IS NOT NULL
UNION  
SELECT "[All]", -2 
UNION  
SELECT "[Open/App] (Trk/Pnd/App)", -1 
UNION 
SELECT "[Open] (Tracking & Pending)", 0
ORDER BY sort_order, STATUS;
```

But it fails when I try to create the view from this. Any suggestions would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes for literals

```
SELECT
      x_doc_status.Status
    , sort_order
FROM x_doc_status
WHERE sort_order IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT
      '[All]'
    , -2
UNION
SELECT
      '[Open/App] (Trk/Pnd/App)'
    , -1
UNION
SELECT
      '[Open] (Tracking & Pending)'
    , 0
ORDER BY
      sort_order
    , STATUS
;
```

I suggest you also use `UNION ALL` instead of just `UNION`. The former is faster because it does not attempt to remove duplicate rows.

Comment: Thanks but it makes no difference, keep getting the error 'You have an error in your SQL syntax'. Tried a shorter version, with just one union, still fails:
DELIMITER $$

ALTER ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `form_report_cbodocstatus` AS (
SELECT
 `x_doc_status`.`Status`     AS `Status`,
 `x_doc_status`.`sort_order` AS `sort_order`
FROM `x_doc_status`
WHERE `x_doc_status`.`sort_order` IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
 '[All]'         AS `Status`, 
 -2        AS `sort_order`
)$$

DELIMITER ;

Comment: What can I tell you? test it at: https://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/ see what it thinks